# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start

Tags: servlets, equinox, eclipse-rap

I'm trying to run for the first time a RAP example app deployed on a tomcat server and I get this error when I call it in the browser:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet equinoxbridgeservlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
equinoxbridgeservlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.
```

The web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp">
  <servlet id="bridge">  
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Equinox Bridge Servlet</display-name>
    <description>Equinox Bridge Servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- Framework Controls could be useful for testing purpose, but
     we disable it per default -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>enableFrameworkControls</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>      
    </init-param>

    <!-- Enable multi-language support for the extension registry -->
    <!-- the OSGi console is useful for trouble shooting but will fill up your 
     appserver log quickly, so deactivate on production use. Uncomment
     the -console parameter to enabled OSGi console access.  -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>commandline</param-name>
      <param-value>-registryMultiLanguage<!-- -console --></param-value>     
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the example app from the bundle org.eclipse.rap.demo.
I followed the instructions to create the WAR file and then i´ve deployed it on a local tomcat (XAMPP). All these programs are up to date and the app compiles and works fine in eclipse.

Please ask me if you need more infos!

EDIT:

hier the full error:

```
Apr 08, 2016 11:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error while starting Framework
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher$ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass0(FrameworkLauncher.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher$ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(FrameworkLauncher.java:1036)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:401)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 08, 2016 11:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SCHWERWIEGEND: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 08, 2016 11:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Allocate exception for servlet equinoxbridgeservlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Show us the full exception stack trace from the logs.

Comment: After a few little adjustments I had to compile a programm for work (this is a very new task for me) but i received this error on my local server as well as on the live server. Therefore I tried with the example above (from the eclipse homepage) to exclude programming errors.
Since I take the same exceptions, I think I have a configuration problem: In the company where i work, our application was till now compiled and uploaded always from another pc (and another employee...).

Comment: After I reinstalled Eclipse I managed to export the projects! I still don't know what happened, maybe a conflict between bundles/targets

Answer (score -1):

Add the below lines in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```